# How to set a 2D index in Play Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

How do I set a 2D index in play morphia?

Example:

```
db.places.ensureIndex( { loc : "2d" } )
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean play 1.2.x.

You can't do this from the @Indexed annotation yet, it seems: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?id=290

You can do it with this somewhat hacky [untested] code:

```
MorphiaPlugin.ds()
   .getMongo()
   .getDB('dbname')
   .getCollection('places')
   .ensureIndex(BasicDBObject(loc, "2d"));
```

But you might just want to do it from the shell, as you show. It's a one time thing.

Comment: Correct, its play 1.2.x. Bummer on the lack of 2D support.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, years later:

```
@Indexes(
        @Index(fields=@Field( value = "location", type= IndexType.GEO2DSPHERE))
)
```

on the `@Entity` class (if the member holding the GeoPoint is called `location`) generates the correct indices for spherical geospatial queries.

Don't forget to set the 4th param of the `.near()` method to `true` (spherical).

Also you should ensure the indices were generated by simply calling `datastore.ensureIndexes()` before querying.